# Can not call API from yandex cloud server, but from local machine it's working fine

Tags: python, flask, yandexcloud

I am running my app with flask on my local PC (Windows) and when I call it with python requests from laptop (macOS):

```
image_url = requests.post(server, params={"user_id" : message.from_user.id, "request_" : message.text, "type_" : type_1}, timeout = 600)
```

It works fine, but when I try to use it from the yandex cloud (ubuntu), it gives me:

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

I guess it is something about secutity protection, but I do not give a clue if the problem is on PC or on cloud

I also tried to change POST method to GET, but no change at all. I probably should change some secutity settings, but I do not how